# Is there a way, from the cmd prompt, to do a dir of files/folders that are only in the path environment variable?

Tags: cmd

I want to search for a file on my C: drive from the cmd prompt.  I can go to the root folder `cd \` and then use `dir/s myfile.txt`.

But I want to just be able to search only those folders that are in my path environment variable.

Can that be done?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
where myfile.txt
```

The search is done in the current active directory and in all the folders enumerated in the `path` variable

Answer (score 0):

Yes, with the following command:

```
for %a in ("%path:;=";"%") do cd %~a && dir /b /s myfile.txt
```